# Definition of uniformly $C^1$-regular boundary: Why last coordinate of diffeomorphism $\mathbb{e_d} \cdot \Phi(y) >0 \iff y \in \Omega $

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, smooth-functions, diffeomorphism

In my partial differential equations class, we introduce Sobolev spaces. We define that for an open, connected set $\Omega$ to have a uniformly $C^1-$regular boundary, it means that there are positive constants $\rho, C$ such that $\forall x \in \partial \Omega,$ there is:

a $C^1$-diffeomorphism $\Phi: \mathbb{B^{d}_\rho(x)} \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ with

- $\sup_{y} ||\Phi'(y)||<C$,
- $\sup_{y} ||\Phi'(y)^{-1}||<C$,
- $\mathbb{e_{d}}\cdot \Phi(y) >0 \iff y \in \Omega \cap \mathbb{B^{d}_\rho(x)}.$

I have little experience with manifolds and submanifolds. I would like to understand:

1. By the second condition, do we mean that the supremum over the preimage of the Jacobian of $\Phi$ is bounded? Do I understand the expression correctly?
2. What is the importance, the implications of the fact that the last coordinate of that diffeomorphism is only positive inside $\Omega?$ Any intuition on this? How should I imagine this condition visually?

$\mathbb{B^{d}_\rho(x)}, \mathbb{B}$ are the ball around point $x$ with radius $\rho$ and the unit ball, both in dimension $d.$

Comment: The last condition means that $\Phi$ always maps the domain to the same half-ball. The fact that it's mapped to a half-ball is the point of the definition: locally $\Omega$ is diffeomorphic to a half-ball. This also means that $\partial \Omega$ is mapped to $\{x_d = 0\}$, i.e. the map flattens the boundary. The fact that it's always the same one (with last coordinate positive) is a technical convenience so you don't have to rotate/keep track of it.
The second condition says that the inverse map $\Phi^{-1}$ (you know it's bijective already) has uniformly bounded derivative.

Comment: @user378654 Wow, thanks so much for the explanation. Very enlightening! So everywhere locally under $\Phi$, $\Omega$ looks like one half of the unit ball. That $\Phi=0$ on the boundary follows from its continuity, right?

And my other question was what is the importance of this fact in the theory of Sobolev spaces? Could you give me a rough idea?

Comment: Maybe a way to think about it is, up to localization and these $C^1$ diffeomorphisms, the class of $C^1$ domains as defined there is equivalent to half-balls. So if you are trying to prove something (esp. something involving the boundary, like trace theorems or approximation by smoother functions), and that statement is also invariant up to constant under $C^1$ diffeomorphism (pretty much anything for $W^{1, p}$ spaces, as they only see one derivative), it suffices to prove it on a half-ball. And on half-balls some things are easier, such as differentiating in tangential vs. normal directions.

Comment: @user378654 thanks a lot, very helpful!